# I want to add a default text value to the output of Free marker template in the first coulmn of the csv

Tags: freemarker

Sample Freemarker Template:

```
Name,RollNo,Class,School,FatherName
<#list doc.Students.student >
<#items as student>
"<#if (student.name)?has_content>${student.name}<#else></#if>",<#t>
"<#if (student.rollNo)?has_content>${student.rollNo}<#else></#if>",<#t>
"<#if (student.class)?has_content>${student.class}<#else></#if>",<#t>
"<#if (student.school)?has_content>${student.class}<#else></#if>",<#t>
"<#if (student.father)?has_content>${student.father}<#else></#if>",<#t>
 </#items>
  Disclaimer: Please indicate acceptance of this offer.
 <#else>
</#list>
```

The above template gives the output in an excel file where the "Disclaimer:" text is on the same row as the student details and in the column after "FatherName"

But I want the "Disclaimer:" text to be on the next row to the student details and in the first column.
Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: If you always want the disclaimer row to be present, just put it after the `<#/list>`. Also why's that `#else` there? Also remove the last `,<#t>`, so it will produce no comma, and a line-break after the last column.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Default value operator !](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_default)

> Default value operator
>   Synopsis: `unsafe_expr!default_expr or unsafe_expr! or (unsafe_expr)!default_expr or (unsafe_expr)!`

This operator allows you to specify a default value for the case when the value is missing.

Comment: Actually I want the default value after the last row in the first column of the csv

Comment: @sreddy you can check `?has_next` see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref_list_accessing_state

Comment: Suppose there are 5 student objects I want the freemarker to create 6th student object with name as "Disclaimer:" and remaining fields as empty